# Find connected video devices

Tags: .net, silverlight, mmppf

Is there a way to see or detect connected screens/video devices in Silverlight? Ultimately I'd like to detect non-HDCP supporting devices. From what I can understand there is a way using VideoOutputConnectors through the LicenseManagement class, but it seems only possible using PlayReady.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with using PlayReady stuff to detect HDCP?